# What determines the load output voltage of this Adafruit solar charger?

Tags: lipo, solar-charge-controller, adafruit

I am looking at [this board](https://www.adafruit.com/product/4755) from Adafruit. It seems like it could work in my project, but I have some concerns about the maximum load output voltage.

My understanding of this board is that I can connect a small solar panel to it, as well as my 5000mAh LiPo battery and the board will "top up" the battery for me.

I can also power my project by connecting my MCU (Particle Boron) to the load output terminals of the board.

The Boron LiPo terminals have an input range of 3.7-4.2V, but the maximum load output of this Adafruit board is 4.4V.

Under what conditions could I expect to see 4.4V? I am not sure that I understand how it works and what conditions would cause the load output to reach 4.4V. Ideally I would like to stay within 3.7-4.2V, but I am not sure if it is possible.

Comment: Please link to a data sheet for the board used plus add a schematic. If you can't find the details then you might as well be asking about any other commercial piece of electronics with no supporting documentation and, under these circumstances, the question will get closed as it implicitly calls for speculation and opinion.

Comment: A 6V at 1A solar panel is not small. The 2V at 40mA solar panel on my solar garden lights is small. If you use a 6V at 100mA solar panel then your 5000mAh battery will take weeks of sunshine to fully charge.

Comment: Andy: I am not sure that there is a datasheet. I will take a closer look though and report back.

Audioguru: The 5000mAh battery would be fully charged before being deployed. The solar would just be to top it off.

Comment: I guess if the battery is full it might stop charging the battery and connect directly to the solar cell? Your microcontroller is probably okay with 4.4V

Answer (score 0):

[The Particle Boron](https://docs.particle.io/assets/pdfs/datasheets/boron-datasheet.pdf) can accept up to 4.4V on its lithium battery input:

[image]

3.3V to 4.4VDC on the Li+ pin.

It can actually tolerate a higher voltage than that, although you should try to avoid it:

[image]

Absolute maximum rating \$V_{LiPo} = 6.5V\$.

Check the datasheets rather than the description on web pages.

The "Load" output of the Adafruit charger board will **not** exceed 4.4V.  The LiPo charger output can exceed 4.4V if that's what it takes to charge the cell.

Use the charger outputs to charge the cell, use the "Load" output to power the Particle Boron and you should be fine.